# Using python to remove nearly identical lines in txt file, with the exception of first and last lines

Tags: string, text

Here is a snippet from a text file I am working on.

http://pastebin.com/4Uba5i4P

I would like to use python to detect those big repeating "~ Move" lines (Which are not identical except for the "~ Move" part.), and remove all but the first and last of those lines.

How I would I start to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file line by line like this:

```
`## Open the file with read only         permit 
f = open('myTextFile.txt') 
## Read the first line 
line = f.readline() 
## If the file is not empty keep   reading line one at a time #
# till the file is empty while line: print line 
line = f.readline() f.close()`
```

With this you could then edit this sample to test each line using a regex like this:

```
`if line.find("~Move") == -1: 
Break;
Else:
Line=Line [5:-1]`
```

Though this assumes that the ~Move is all at the beginning of the line. Hope this helps, if not leave a comment and I'll try and help.